# Wait until function is complete

Tags: javascript

After some help in another thread, I now have a working code that waits 3000 and then sets a variable to 1.  A loop then checks every 1000 until that variable has changed and then alerts

```js
var myvalue;

setTimeout(function() {
  myvalue = 1;
}, 3000);

function check() {
  if (myvalue == 1) {
    alert("Value Is Set");
  } else {
    setTimeout(check, 1000);
  }
}

alert("debug1");
check();
alert("debug2");
```

My problem now is that it does not wait until the `check()` function has completed before moving on.  I have added some debug `alert`s and can see that all is fired at once.

How can I make it wait without using a timeout?

Comment: This seems like a ***very*** X/Y problem. Polling is never a very good idea, and there is nearly always a much better solution. Is there no way you can raise/listen for an event when the variable is changed instead?

Comment: Do research/learn about callback functions ... i think you need that'

Comment: in which action do you want this function.?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a callback and call it when the function will done.

Like this:

```js
var myvalue;

setTimeout(function() {
  myvalue = 1;
}, 3000);

function check(callback) {
  if (myvalue == 1) {
    alert("Value Is Set");
    callback && callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(check, 1000, callback);
  }
}

alert("debug1");
check(function() {
  alert("debug2");
});
```

Comment: I am confused because if i add another alert after the check function then it still executes that at the beginning - I want it to wait until the check function has completed before moving on

Comment: It's because `setTimeout()` is effectively asynchronous - hence you need to use the callback pattern as this answer suggests

Comment: @fightstarr20 You need to put the code that you want that will run **after** the original function in the callback (Just like it did)

Comment: @fightstarr20 is it answer your question?